# Как ведут себя inline-block элементы

Tags: html, display

Здравствуйте, у меня возник вопрос по поводу поведения элементов на странице, с чередованием свойства `display:block;`и `display:inline-block;`. Я создал 3 дива и в каждый поместил еще по 3 div, нужно сделать так, что бы было возможно распологать как угодно внутренние div, но что бы внешние div не меняли свою позицию. Собственно я думал, что в этом никаких проблем не будет, но почему-то при разных комбинациях этого самого display: внешние div блоки начали вмещаться по вертикали, почему это происходит, ведь если я правильно понимаю, `display:inline-block` должен везти себя просто как строка и не зависеть от того, что в нем находится, аналогично с просто `display:block`. Что я упускаю? Как же все таки ведут себя блоки, стилизованные таким образом?

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
body,
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:black;">
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#4cff00;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#194e00;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#4cff00; "></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#194e00; display:block;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-color:blue;">
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green; display:block;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#4cff00;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#194e00;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы исправить, задайте `vertical-align` для контейнеров, например, `top`.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
body,
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:black;">
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#4cff00;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#194e00;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#4cff00; "></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#194e00; display:block;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-color:blue;">
  <div class="content" style="background-color:green; display:block;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#4cff00;"></div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color:#194e00;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Точно! Но все же, с чем связан эффект от display?

Comment: Точно не смогу сказать. По-умолчанию вертикальное выравнивание идет по базовой линии текста. В этом расчете участвуют интерлиньяж (`line-height`) и высоты всех строчных и строчно-блочных элементов в строке. У вас высота строчно-блочных контейнеров задана явно, но в расчете, судя по всему, принимает участие и выравнивание внутренних элементов, которые оказывают свое влияние на высоту контейнера.